# Composer fails to update with zfcUser

Tags: zend-framework, module, composer-php

I try to install zfcUser with composer, installed ZfcBase and ZfcAdmin with success but
zfcUser is failing?

composer.json;

```
   {
        "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
        "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
        "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
        "keywords": [
            "framework",
            "zf2"
        ],
        "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.3.3",
            "zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.*",
            "zf-commons/zfc-base": "dev-master",
            "zf-commons/zfc-admin": "dev-master",
            "zf-commons/zfc-user": "~0.1.2"
        }
    }
```

update result of composer:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install zf-commons/zfc-base v0.1.2
    - Conclusion: remove zendframework/zendframework 2.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.2.3
    - Installation request for zf-commons/zfc-user ~0.1.2 -> satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-user[0.1.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.2.2
    - Installation request for zf-commons/zfc-base dev-master -> satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-base[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.2.1
    - zf-commons/zfc-user 0.1.2 requires zf-commons/zfc-base 0.* -> satisfiable by zf-commons/zfc-base[0.0.1, 0.1.0, 0.1.1, v0.1.2].
    - zf-commons/zfc-base 0.0.1 requires zendframework/zendframework 2.0.* -> satisfiable by zendframework/zendframework[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8].
    - zf-commons/zfc-base 0.1.0 requires zendframework/zendframework 2.1.* -> satisfiable by zendframework/zendframework[2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5].
    - zf-commons/zfc-base 0.1.1 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib 2.1.* -> satisfiable by zendframework/zendframework[2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5], zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zendframework[2.2.0, 2.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zendframework[2.2.0, 2.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zendframework[2.2.0, 2.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zendframework[2.2.0, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zendframework[2.2.0, 2.0.4].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zendframework[2.2.0, 2.0.5].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zendframework[2.2.0, 2.0.6].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zendframework[2.2.0, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zendframework[2.2.0, 2.0.8].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zendframework[2.2.0, 2.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zendframework[2.2.0, 2.1.1].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zendframework[2.2.0, 2.1.2].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zendframework[2.2.0, 2.1.3].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zendframework[2.2.0, 2.1.4].
    - Can only install one of: zendframework/zendframework[2.2.0, 2.1.5].
    - don't install zendframework/zend-stdlib 2.1.0|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.2.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-stdlib 2.1.1|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.2.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-stdlib 2.1.2|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.2.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-stdlib 2.1.3|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.2.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-stdlib 2.1.4|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.2.0
    - don't install zendframework/zend-stdlib 2.1.5|don't install zendframework/zendframework 2.2.0
    - Installation request for zendframework/zendframework 2.2.* -> satisfiable by zendframework/zendframework[2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4].
```

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly requiring the Zend Framework version `2.2.*`, but the components you also use require version `2.1.*` - this will never work.

Either make the Zfc-components upgrade their requirements, or do use an older Zend Framework. Try including `"zendframework/zendframework" : "*"` as a starter and see what happens.